# `StreamSocketListener`-based server in Universal App

Tags: xaml, visual-c++, windows-10, uwp

It is known that Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 put lots of constraints on background activities of third-party app. For instance, it is impossible to develop server-like capability (e.g. BitTorrent) in Store App without having to keep the screen always-on using `DisplayRequest`.

From the latest documentation, I have a feeling that one can utilize the method [EnableTransferOwnership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn879542.aspx) of [StreamSocketListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn879542.aspx) to delegate the usual request processing code to a background task. The problem is that I don't know how [IBackgroundTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.ibackgroundtask.aspx) should work in this case. Normally, they are activated by some conditions/triggers such as "Internet becomes available". The only sensible trigger in this case seems to be [ControlChannelTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.controlchanneltrigger.aspx) but apparently, the documentation implies that it cannot be used with `StreamSocketListener` since the app needs to be the one who creates and register a `StreamSocket`, not waiting for the socket to be created by some connecting client.

Is it possible now to implement a `StreamSocketListener`-based server in Windows 10 Universal app platform? If it is, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it to activate a background task on socket activity such as receiving data when the app is not active, e.g.:

```
var socketTaskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
socketTaskBuilder.Name = "SocketActivityBackgroundTask";
socketTaskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = "SocketActivityBackgroundTask.SocketActivityTask";
var trigger = new SocketActivityTrigger();
socketTaskBuilder.SetTrigger(trigger);
var task = socketTaskBuilder.Register();

socket = new StreamSocket();
socket.EnableTransferOwnership(task.TaskId, SocketActivityConnectedStandbyAction.Wake);
```

For a complete example, look at the [Socket Activity sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket) or the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.socketactivitytrigger).

Comment: Thanks. It is great to know that it is now possible to achieve such basic functionality. I am still blur on how `TransferOwnership` works i.e. how to move my original code to handle the request in `StreamSocketListener` to the background task but I should be able to figure that out from the example. Hope that there will be an official documentation on API changes.